# How does one change the network tier from premium to standard in Google cloud platform

Tags: google-cloud-networking

I am currently running a VM instance which automatically assigned me a premium static ip address in the google cloud platform. My usage requirements are not high and to keep the costs low I would convert the plan into a standard network tier while maintaining the same static IP.
Any insights into the same?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

**If you change external IP from premium to standard tier you will get another IP (it will basically change). There's no way to keep it in this situation.**

You will be able to use load balancing and other features but all external IP's will be regional then.

You can have a look at [GCP's standar tier](https://cloud.google.com/network-tiers/docs/overview#standard_tier) documentation to have a better understainding how it works and it's limitations. It may also be helpful for you to look at [service tier's documentation](https://cloud.google.com/network-tiers/docs/using-network-service-tiers#creating_static_external_addresses) too - it explains how external IP's behave.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you change your IP address to "Ephemeral", and then you can select Standard, then you can reserve a new IP address in the standard tier. Naturally you  will then need to update your DNS.